# how to check if user had entered his data before

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm working on this php,mysql and If the user entered some information in a Sign Up page and the information stored in a db , if the user again entered the same information again HOW should I check that before sending the info again to the db ?

I'm using localhost as my server .

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "hotelsava";
$dberror1 = " Could not connect to the database ! ";
$connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();

}
else
{
    echo 'DB Connected';
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];

    $faname = $_POST['faname'];

    $em = $_POST['em'];

    $em2 = $_POST['em2'];

    $Uaname = $_POST['Uaname'];

    $pwd1 = $_POST['pwd1'];

    $pwd2 = $_POST['pwd2'];

    $cardt = $_POST['cardt'];

    $cardnum = $_POST['cardnum'];

    $cardco = $_POST['cardco'];

    $namecard = $_POST['namecard'];




    $query = "INSERT INTO signuptable (fname,faname,em,em2,Uaname,pwd1,pwd2,cardt,cardnum,cardco,namecard)VALUES ('$fname','$faname', '$em', '$em2','$Uaname','$pwd1', '$pwd2', '$cardt', ' $cardnum','$cardco', '$namecard')";


    $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);

    if($result==1)
    {
        echo ' sucessful';
        $status="done";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo ' failed';
         $status="notdone";
    }



    }

?>


<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="hotelprojectstyle.css">
         <title>Sign Up</title>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   </head>
   <body>
        <?php
            include 'Header.php';
        ?>

        <h2 id="signup">Sign Up</h2>
        <?php if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status']==="done") { ?>
        <p> successfully register</p>  
        <?php header("Location: Homepage.php?status=$status"); ?>
        <?php } else {if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status']==="notdone") { ?>
             <p>Sorry the registration has been failed</p>
             <?php } else { ?>
         <form name="signupform" action="SignUpPage.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return signuptable();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <table>
                 <tbody>
                     <tr><td><b>Personal Information</b></td></tr>
                     <tr>

                         <td><label for="fname"> First Name </label></td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><span class="error"> * </span></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="faname"> Family Name </label></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" name="faname" id="faname" </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <label for="em">Email</label></td>
                        <td> <input type="email" name="em" id="em"><span class="error"> * </span></td>
                        <td> <label for="em2">Repeat Email</label></td>
                        <td> <input type="email" name="em2" id="em2"><span class="error"> * </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="gender"> Gender</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="">Male</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked="">female</td>

                   </tr>

                   <tr><td><b>Log-in Information</b></td></tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td> <label for="Uaname"> Username </label></td>
                       <td> <input type="text" name="Uaname" id="Uaname"><span class="error"> * </span></td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                       <td><label for="pwd1">Password</label></td>
                       <td><input type="Password" name="pwd1" id="pwd1"><span class="error"> * </span></td>

                       <td>  <label for="pwd2">Repeat Password</label></td>
                       <td><input type="Password" name="pwd2" id="pwd2"><span class="error"> * </span></td>

                   </tr>
                   <tr><td><b>Payment Information</b></td></tr>

                   <tr>
                       <td><label for="cardt">Card Type</label></td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="cardt" id="cardt"><span class="error"> * </span></td> 


                       <td><label for="cardnum">Card Number</label></td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="cardnum" id="cardnum"><span class="error"> * </span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                       <td><label for="cardco">Card Code</label></td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="cardco" id="cardco"><span class="error"> * </span></td>

                       <td><label for="namecard">Name on Card</label></td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="namecard" id="namecard"><span class="error"> * </span></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr><td id="colo">*  Required Field</td></tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="validate()"></td> 
                 </tr>


          </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
         <?php } } ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
                var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

                var namee = document.signupform.fname.value;
                if(namee==="")
                {
                  spans[0].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("h").style.background="pink";
                }
                var em1 = document.signupform.Em.value;
                if(em1==="")
                {
                  spans[1].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("i").style.background="pink";
                }
                var em22 = document.signupform.em2.value;
                if(em22==="")
                {
                  spans[2].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("j").style.background="pink";
                }
                var unamee = document.signupform.Uaname.value;
                if(unamee==="")
                {
                  spans[3].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("k").style.background="pink";
                }
                var pwaa1 = document.signupform.pwd.value;
                if(pwaa1==="")
                {
                  spans[4].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("p1").style.background="pink";
                }
                var pwaa2 = document.signupform.pwd2.value;
                if(pwaa2==="")
                {
                  spans[5].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("p2").style.background="pink";
                }
                var cardtt = document.signupform.cardt.value;
                if(cardtt==="")
                {
                  spans[6].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("l").style.background="pink";
                }
                var cardnuum= document.signupform.cardnum.value;
                if(cardnuum==="")
                {
                  spans[7].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("m").style.background="pink";
                }
                var cardcoo = document.signupform.cardco.value;
                if(cardcoo==="")
                {
                  spans[8].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("n").style.background="pink";
                }
                var namecardd1 = document.signupform.namecard.value;
                if(namecardd1==="")
                {
                  spans[9].style.visibility="visible";
                  document.getElementById("oo").style.background="pink";
                }


            }
      </script>





    <?php
    include ('Footer.php');
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Be more specific, post your actual code, please.

Comment: Run a conditional select and count, or num_rows >0

Comment: your table structure please

Answer (score 0):

You can check by matching **Email Id** for every user. If a user is already exist with that Email id in your database, you can skip this user by showing some specific message.

Comment: This can also be posted as comment